# How to identify colliding faces/objects in the scene?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, color, collision

I have multiple objects in a scene I'm working on. Some of these objects are entering each other, I have to move my view to find where I need to make adjustments.

Instead of having to keep changing my view, is there an Indicator function that shows me where two separate faces/objects are colliding.

What I've tried to do:

- X - Ray wasn't as helpful.
- In the Viewport shading option, I have changed the color to random, hoping when two colors collide a new color could be an indicator, but it didn't really work that way.

Is there something I can do?

Comment: If your scene is not to large, you could combine all your objects into one, then use Mesh Analysis to see intersecting faces, then undo the join... Bit of a hack but it would work